# Which kernel does 12.10 require?

Tags: 12.10, kernel, security

Earlier this week Software Updater installed `linux-image 3.5.0.26` which caused my 2 systems to become extremely unstable. I have locked in Grub the version I'm using to `3.5.0.24`.

Today Software Updated informed about security upgrades. How can I determine whether the security updates will install on the selected kernel, or whether a new kernel will be downloaded?

```
$ uname -a
Linux pfeiffep-HPE-580t 3.5.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 01:50:30 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

apt-cache policy linux-image
linux-image: Installed: (none) Candidate: 3.5.0.25.31
```

Is this indicative that 3.5.0.24 is currently installed? Will the security patches be installed on 3.5.0.24?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-cache policy linux-image linux-image-generic` will tell you the "latest" kernel version (those two meta-packages depend on "the latest kernel").

So you will see that currently 3.5.0.25 is the latest which would get pulled in by security updates.

About what is currently running on your system, you can see it in the output of `uname -a`: `3.5.0-24-generic`.

And when security patches are applied to a kernel its version get "bumped" up, so if there are security patches needed you will get the with 3.5.0.24 **or** any next version. So it is possible for you to skip 3.0.25 and just wait for the next (or later) update.

*On one of my machines I had to skip 3.5.23 and 3.5.24 for instance.*

Comment: linux-image:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.5.0.25.31    Is this indicative that 3.5.0.24 is currently installed. Will the security patches be installed on 3.5.0.24?